# Can not get response from urllib.request.urlopen with an url ending with a dot

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I have a script looking like this, with a username ending with a "." dot.

```
import urllib.request

url = "https://likee.video/@evadecarle."
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
print(response)
```

The ending dot "." in the url seems to cause a problem.
If I change the url to `url = "https://likee.video/@11Happyness07.12"` it works fine.
How do I make it work with the ending dot "." ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we try to fetch `https://likee.video/@evadecarle.` using `urllib.requests`, we see:

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://likee.video/@evadecarle.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: Moved Temporarily
>>>
```

It's failing because the remote website is returning a 302 status code
(an http redirect). Normally, you would handle this by using an
`HTTPRedirectHandler`, something like:

```
>>> opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler(), urllib.request.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0))
>>> resp = opener.open('https://google.com')
>>> resp.url
'https://www.google.com/'
```

Unfortunately, the URL `https://likee.video/@evadecarle.` is an odd
one: it returns a `302` status code, but doesn't include a `Location:`
header identifying the redirect target.

Because of this, it looks like `urllib` doesn't handle it properly.
Someone else may correct me on this, but it looks like the `requests`
library handles this without a problem:

```
>>> resp = requests.get('https://likee.video/@evadecarle.')
>>> resp
<Response [302]>
>>> resp.text[:80]
'<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="robots" c'
```

So using the `requests` module may be the simplest solution.